# Where are syslog files?

Tags: 16.04, syslog

So if I run `journalctl` I see loads of kernel based commands but if I look at /`var/log/syslog` it is empty. I would like to setup swatch to monitor the journal but I ultimately need to know where the log is actually located. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe syslog service is stopped. Type `sudo systemctl status syslog` to see if it's running.  If it's running,  `cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` to see where it is saving log files.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `/var/log` directory.

Kernel messages can be found in `/var/log/kern.log`

You are welcome to take a look at the manuals or wikis:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

As @Redbob stated, the location of the saved log files can be found in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file:

```
cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```